# #CDC "Send failure: 501 out of bounds exception" while sending data to a server

Tags: c#, c

I have an out of bounds exception even when I defined the bounds range? I'm fairly new to the custom engine so I looked this up and there were no relevant results.

Here is my code:

```
#CDC /Project.plg / 
function Send(sender n, receiver s) {

linear st = new IndexRange
st.sender(n, s.timeout())

t = n.senderTimeout / 2
n.Send(packet:"5000",value:"5",Timer t)
s.ttl(t)

bounds n
    {
    for (t != null)
    n.SendOption(t, st, n.packetRange(true))
    return; st.Status.ToString()
    }



}
/Project.plg   / #CDC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the bounds for "n" but didn't call the "n.packetIndex()" range along with the packet range you put.

You also must invoke the boundary after you send the packet or you will get a "Netty Timeout" compile error when running the .plg.

```
bounds n
    {

    for (t != null)
    n.sendOption(t, st, n.packetIndex(this.packetRange(true, 1), for n.packetIndex PIN)
    Sweep;
    returns; n + st.status.toString()
    n.sends.maxBoundary(st, this.range(Random rand for Exc != st))
        sweep:
            n.packetRange(index, t)
            t.Range(timeoutRange.index).Default().invoke()
    }
```

If your network method does not include "SWEEP" then you can use the "indexarray" method.

```
bounds n
    {

    for (t != null)
    n.sendOption(t, st, n.packetIndex(this.packetRange(true, 1), for n.packetIndex PIN)
    st.indexRange.Default().invoke()
    returns; n + st.status.toString()
    n.sends.maxBoundary(st, this.range(Random rand for Exc != st))
        boundaryIndex i = new n.sendOption
            t.alias.toString(n)
                st : t != true {

            n.packetRange(index, t)
            t.Range(timeoutRange.index).Default().invoke()

                    }
    }
```

If you use the second method put a "#CDC-CommonIndex" tag along with all of your called tags.

```
s : st.senderRange(index)

$
/ 
#CDC-CommonIndex
#CDC-Plugin
#CDC-Net
/
$
```

Honestly you're really fortunate that I stumbled upon your question, I don't think this forum even supports #CDC plugin development. You're welcome.

Comment: On the last code thingy you put ` s : st.senderRange(index) `, but I don't have a sender range called in the n.Send(); function? How would I do that in advance?

Comment: @CodeMaster85 Where you have `function Send(sender s, receiver n)`, you have to replace that with `function Send(new Sender s, delegate receiver n, boundary CDC.Bounds.Arg())` but make sure to insert another tag at the bottom named " `#CDC-Bounds` ".

Comment: I ran your code @JaySura and it worked! But there's one problem: It doesn't recognize "delegate receiver" so it won't run the entire function. How would I fix this?

Comment: @CodeMaster85 At the top, can you put this: `CDC.Engine.Method delegate = new Methods(delegate)`

Comment: It works! Or at least it didn't show any errors or compiling errors, it seems to be sending 50GbPs to the requested server!

Comment: @CodeMaster85 Uhm that's insane?